# bar plot - creating positive labels on negative axis - scale_y_continuous() not working

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'd like to make a plot of workers' salary grades and compare people who are home based with people who are office based.

I would like one set of bars (in colour) represent the people in my data frame that are home based, and the other set of bars (in black) represent the people that are office based.

The problem is that I'd like the orientation of the plot to be the opposite of `ggplots()`'s default (see drawing of desired plot below). When I try to address the labeling with `scale_y_continuous()` my code breaks (I use `scale_y_continuous()` because I've first used `coord_flip()`).

Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

```
# Data 
df <- data.frame(question = c("work", "work", "work", "work", "work", "work"),
                 location = c("homebased", "homebased", "homebased", "officebased", "officebased", "officebased"),
                 salary = c("grade 1/2", "grade 3", "grade 4/5", " grade 1/2", "grade 3", "grade 4/5"),
                 freq = c(41.3, 53.5, 5.2, 37.2, 54.3, 9.5))

# Prep data to change direction of default plot
df$freq <- df$freq*-1

# Plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mapping = aes(x = question, y = freq, fill = factor(salary))) +
  geom_col(data = df[df$location == "homebased", ], position = "dodge") +
  geom_col(data = df[df$location == "officebased", ], aes(group = salary),
           fill = "black", width = 0.45, position = position_dodge(width = 0.9))  + 
  coord_flip () +  theme_classic() +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "", position = "top") +      
  scale_y_continuous("freq", limits = c(0, -60), breaks =c(-60, -40, -20, 0),
                     labels = c(60, 40, 20, 0))
```

Comment: Change to `limits = c(-60, 0)`. "_If the larger value comes first, the scale will be reversed_" seems to cause trouble.

Comment: Or easier: skip `df$freq <- df$freq*-1` and the `scale_y_continuous` stuff, and use `scale_y_reverse(limits = c(60, 0))` instead.